# Parallel time function and non-blocking input

Tags: python, time, parallel-processing, nonblocking

I do not code with python but I have to write a simple game in python, the process is the program make 2 random numbers and ask the user what is the sum of these two numbers and the user have 5 seconds to answer it if it gets more than 5 seconds it should says Time Out and show the point, else if the user answered correctly under 5 second it should terminate or kill the time function, make other random numbers and ask the sum of them

the input function blocks the program and wait for input so I have made two processes and I'm not sure I did right or no, it still doesn't work in parallel also looks like the sleep function blocks the program too

I have search a lot about parallel programming and non-blocking input in python but I couldn't fix it

```
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

point = int(0)

check = bool(False)

def runInParallel(*fns):
  proc = []
  for fn in fns:
    p = Process(target=fn)
    p.start()
    proc.append(p)
  for p in proc:
    p.join()


def timeingFunc():
    timer = int(3)
    time.sleep(timer)
    print("Time Out")
    print(point)



def logic():
    counter = 0
    +(+counter)
    x = random.getrandbits(2)
    y = random.getrandbits(2)

    print("%3f + %2f = " % (x, y))
    result = int(input())




    if result == int (x + y):
       +(+point)
       print("Good")
       check = True






if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1>0:
        runInParallel(logic(),timeingFunc())
```

Comment: you have to use function's name without `()` - it is called "callback" - `runInParallel(logic, timeingFunc)` - and later `Process` will automatically use `()` to run it.

Comment: you can use `point = 0` `check = False` instaead of `point = int(0)`, `check = bool(False)`

Comment: i don't know what do you try to do with `+(+point)` and `+(+counter)` but if you want increate value then you need `point += 1`

Comment: instead of `while 1>0:` you can use very popular `while True:`

Comment: `multiprocessing` runs two separated processes which don't share variables - so `timeingFunc` will always print `0` points. `threading` shares variables between threads.

Comment: `runInParallel` will print `Time Out` but it can't stop `logic` and `logic` will still wait for answer. it is simpler to control it in `GUI` than in `text application`

Comment: @furas Thanks a lot for your explanations, I am new to python I didn't know these things.

Comment: and yes I agree that it's much simpler in `GUI Application` but it's force right now to do it with `Console Application`, I'm gonna try doing this with `threading` thanks but there is still a big problem how to stop `logic` and do not wait for an answer!?

Comment: and in this single poblem `multiprocessing` can be better then `threading` because it has method `process.terminate()`. So when process with `timeingFunc` finish job and its `join()` also returns then you could run `other_process.terminate()`. You could even run only `logic` in separated `process` and `timeingFunc` run in current process.

Comment: well very nice, one more time thanks a lot

Comment: I'm gonna try this hope it works

Comment: i tried to write it but with `Process` but `Process` doesn't have access to terminal window and `input()` can't get data :) This seems more complicated.

Comment: module [inputimeout](https://github.com/johejo/inputimeout) seems interesting - it uses `selectors` for Linux or `msvcrt` for Windows. [source code](https://github.com/johejo/inputimeout/blob/master/inputimeout/inputimeout.py)